Why is my serial communication slower on a different computer?
I'm making a software to communicate in serial (over USB) with multiple (4 to 5) external devices. Some device are connected through a USB 3.0 hub.
I use polling to get some data from each devices with 3 polling (of ~8-10 Hz) per device except one who has only one (slower) polling (~3 Hz).
I set that if I don't get a value after a time (generally the delay between each query, ex: 125 ms), I ignore the missing value as it can happen. If there are too many consecutive timeout I consider that the connection is broken.
Sometimes, the software will also send a different query (not polled) with a longer timeout as the answer speed is not too important.
I've noticed that when on my main developement computer (a tower), I have very few timeout but when using the machine which should be connected to the devices (a laptop) I have way more timeout.
So my question is, what can throttle the serial communication that is not the connected devices?
My guess would be the CPU or maybe the RAM (but I have doubts) or MB but I don't poll that heavily so I thought the communication should not be impacted.
I tried on another laptop (B) and I have better results than the first laptop (A) but worse than the tower.
I tried to poll as little as possible for my need and I don't think I will change much of that.
For info, the specs are as such:
Tower:

Model: Custom build
CPU: i5-11600K (NOT overclocked)
RAM: 32GB DDR4 3200MHz
MB: MSI B560M-A Pro
OS: Windows 10 64 bit

Laptop A (the slower one):

Model: Dell Latitude 3520
CPU: i5-1135G7
RAM: 16GB DDR 3200 Mhz
MB: Unknown
OS: Windows 11 64 bit

Laptop B:

Model: Dell Precision 7530
CPU: i7-8850H
RAM: 16GB DDR4 2666 Mhz
MB: Unknown
OS: Windows 10 64 bit

If the hardware is the problem and I must change the computer I use (laptop B not available for that other than tests), what should I take, what should I focus on? Can I take a laptop or do I need to make a small tower with custom specs?
EDIT:
To add more information following Robert questions, one device is connected through a serial-to-usb adapter (Aten uc232a) but all the other are only through an USB cable. If there is a converter in device, I don't know but in my C# code I always send data through SerialPort class and nothing else.
All devices see an increase in timeout occurences when on the laptops.
All my serial configuration are the same (except for r/w timeout)

Baud: 115200
DataBits: 8
StopBits: 1
Parity: None
R/W Timeout : 3000 (for the device I have more timeouts with and that I need more stable). Other devices timeout are between 100 and 2000.

Note again that it's the same configuration on the other computers but I still get more timeouts on the laptops.

By "serial communication (over USB)" you mean just USB or do you use USB to serial converter? Even if USB is the abbreviation for "Universal Serial Bus" nobody would call using it a serial communication, just USB in difference to the old RS232 or RS485 serial connections. If you use real serial connections what USB-to-Serial hardware adapter do you use?

I edited my post to hopefully answer your question. Ask away if still unclear.

If you are able to use the other devices using SerialPort class then those USB devices appear as virtual serial port in Windows device manager. Thus from OS perspective they act as a real serial port. What I don't understand is that for searial port it is important to configure them correctly before using them (baud rate, flow control stop bits...) especially the baud rate should have an impact on the timing, but you haven't even mentioned the used configuration...

Yeah sorry didn't think it would be relevent as it was slowing down on the laptops despite having the same serial configuration.
Updated post (again)

Have you done a thorough test to confirm the ONLY things impacting the slow vs fast connections are the computers? As in, testing both on the desktop and the laptop using the exact same settings, cables, and convertors. Have you checked power management on the laptop?

125ms is pretty huge. Normally this stuff is 100% reliable - the app I work on at work does USB-to-FTDI all day long with very small latency.
Two possibilities to consider:

the USB is on a hub and all the bandwidth is being stolen by something else (external disk, USB monitor?)

the CPU timeslices are being stolen by something else. This is annoyingly common on Windows, especially due to antivirus software, and it's also hard to debug.


Do you have enough logic analyzer kit to be able to determine whether the delay is in the PC side or on the actual serial side of the serial? Could there be data loss or corruption on that side? What baud rate is it?

No external disk or USB monitor. Only other thing is a mouse.
I can find some logic analyzer kit I think. I'll have to check this.
Baud rate is not the same on all devices but the one that has the most timeout and that I need the most to be stable has a baud rate of 115200

If you were experiencing 125ms lag on USB per se, you'd notice that on the USB mouse. Which suggests that something else is going on.

@Bainion - "Baud rate is not the same on all devices" - Why are you using a different baud rate? At this point you cannot discount the different in baud rate as being part of the problem.

Correction, sorry. I checked and baudrate is the same on every devices. Still it could be different as those are all different types of devices. It's more of a coincidence that they have the same. I sometimes communicate with yet another one with (this time for real) a different serial configuration because it requires it.
I edited my post to add some informations.
